# Cannot autowire argument $redis of "App\Controller\HomeController::saveComments()": such service exists

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Всем добрый день! Пытаюсь подключить в контроллер Редис

```
    class HomeController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/page/{slug}", name="slug")
         */
        public function page(string $slug, RedisInterface $redis) {

            $userComments = $redis->getComment();
            return $this->render("$slug.html.twig", ['comments' => $userComments]);
        }
    }
```

Создала в Сервисе два класса, один из которых интерфейс, другой - наследуемый от него класс

и подключила в контроллере,  летит ошибка

**Cannot autowire argument $redis of "App\Controller\HomeController::saveComments()": it references interface "App\Service\RedisInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?**

вот класс интерфейса

```
    interface RedisInterface
{

    function getComment();

    function save(string $name, string $comments);
}
```

и реализуемый этот интерфейс класс

```
    class Redis implements RedisInterface
{
    private $redis;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->redis = new Client();
    }
    function getComment()
    {
        $fields = $this->redis->hgetall('comments');

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            yield unserialize($field);
        }
    }

    function save(string $name, string $comments)
    {

        $serializedData = serialize(['name' => $name, 'comment' => $comments]);
        $this->redis->incr('userCount');
        $this->redis->hset('comments', $this->redis->get('userCount'), $serializedData);
    }
}
```

совсем не понимаю, откуда эта ошибка - гугл мне не подсказывает, заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: `namespace` для классов верно прописаны?